# Convert dummy variables to continuous variables

Tags: stata

I have group membership encoded as dummy variables as follows:

```
     +--------------------------+
     | group1   group2   group3 |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |      0        1        0 |
  2. |      0        0        1 |
  3. |      0        0        1 |
  4. |      0        1        0 |
  5. |      1        0        0 |
  6. |      1        0        0 |
  7. |      1        0        0 |
  8. |      1        0        0 |
     +--------------------------+
```

I would like to convert the three `groupX` variables into a single variable as follows:

```
group
2
3
3
2
1
1
1
1
```

This is kind of the "reverse" of doing `xi i.group`, creating a categorical variable from dummies.

I thought `egen foo = group(group*)` but it seems to code the resulting variable oddly:

```
     +--------------------------------+
     | group1   group2   group3   foo |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |      0        1        0     2 |
  2. |      0        0        1     1 |
  3. |      0        0        1     1 |
  4. |      0        1        0     2 |
  5. |      1        0        0     3 |
     |--------------------------------|
  6. |      1        0        0     3 |
  7. |      1        0        0     3 |
  8. |      1        0        0     3 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

Notice that `egen` has coded group 3 as 1, and group 1 as 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to presuppose strong assumptions that variables already have suffixes 1 up and that the indicator variables are disjoint.

That being so, this is an alternative to your code:

```
input group1 group2 group3 
 0 1 0 
 0 0 1 
 0 0 1 
 0 1 0 
 1 0 0 
 1 0 0 
 1 0 0 
 1 0 0 
end 
gen group = group1 
forval j = 2/3 { 
    replace group = `j' if group`j' 
}
```

The rationale for the ordering of `egen, group(`*varlist*`)` is that its results depend on the ordering after `sort` *varlist* which in your case puts `0 0 1` first, `0 1 0` second, and `1 0 0` last, as `0` sorts before `1` on Stata's rules and the ordering is first on the first variable, second on the second variable, and so forth.  This function of `egen` is designed for grouping any combination of variables. numeric (indicator or otherwise) or string.

EDIT: This technique is more general. A key assumption remains that 1 occurs just once in each observation for a set of variables. But there are no assumptions about the number of variables and the variable names need not have the some prefix: you would just need to replace `group*` by something giving the actual variable names.

```
. egen sgroup = concat(group*) 

. gen group = strpos(sgroup, "1") 

. l 

     +-------------------------------------------+
     | group1   group2   group3   sgroup   group |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. |      0        1        0      010       2 |
  2. |      0        0        1      001       3 |
  3. |      0        0        1      001       3 |
  4. |      0        1        0      010       2 |
  5. |      1        0        0      100       1 |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  6. |      1        0        0      100       1 |
  7. |      1        0        0      100       1 |
  8. |      1        0        0      100       1 |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This solution has the advantage of being easy to understand. Also, thanks for the explanation of why `egen, group` was doing what it was doing. One teeny downside to this is that you have to know in advance how many groups you have (i.e. `2/3` is a bit [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)-esque.)

Comment: What generalisation do you seek? Your example is highly structured, but which assumption(s) do you want to relax? If you want general code for `group1` up, then you would program counting the number of such variables. Without any assumptions whatever, you end up re-creating `egen, group()`.

Comment: Agreed. I think I was perhaps overly perturbed by the coding of `egen, group()`, when in fact in many use cases it makes no difference how the resulting variable is encoded.

Comment: @LondonRob Technique added is more general

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very clumsy way of doing it, but I'm sure there are slicker ways:

```
gen id = _n
reshape long group, i(id)
drop if group == 0
drop group id
rename _j group
```

Which results in:

```
     +-----------------+
     | group   country |
     |-----------------|
  1. |     2       FOO |
  2. |     3       FOO |
  3. |     3       FOO |
  4. |     2       BAR |
  5. |     1       BAR |
  6. |     1       BAR |
  7. |     1       BAR |
  8. |     1       BAR |
     +-----------------+
```